# Нужно преобразовать типы php

Tags: php, wordpress, преобразование-типов

День добрый. Собственно в попытках преобразовать string в int:

```php
    $amount_form = $order->get_formatted_order_total(); //получаем значение 
    17.0m(str)
    $amount_form = strtok($amount_form, "."); //здесь имеем 17(str)
    $amount_form = intval($amount_form);
```

В итоге я последней $amount_form я получаю 0. Почему не 17(int)?
Спасибо заранее

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Метод `get_formatted_order_total` возвращает отформатированное значение стоимости заказа, это значит что в вашей строке не только число но также и html теги. Для того чтобы получить стоимость заказа без форматирование нужно использовать метод `get_total` который вернет вам значение типа float либо ничего

```
$amount_form = intval($order->get_total());
```

Подробнее по ссылкам:
https://wp-kama.ru/plugin/woocommerce/function/WC_Order::get_formatted_order_total
https://wp-kama.ru/plugin/woocommerce/function/WC_Abstract_Order::get_total

Comment: гигантское спасибо! Все получилось